# Build component JAR excluding certain dependencies

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am building a component which uses Hibernate, Spring and other modules (built internally). I am using an Ant script. I cannot upgrade to Maven or any other tool.

Please help me build this component JAR file without including any Hibernate JARs, Spring JARs, or other dependent module files. I don't want to include these JAR files because the modules which use this service will have related JARs by default.

Let me know if I am not clear in explaining.

**EDIT**:
Added the code

```
@Service("eventNofitySvc")
public class EventNotificationSvcImpl implements EventNotificationSvc {
@Resource(name = "eventNotifyDao")
private EventNotificationDao eventNotifyDao;

@Override
public void insertEventNotification(EventNotificationVO aPEventNotifyVo) {
        eventNotifyDao.insertEventNotification(aPEventNotifyVo);
}
}

@Service("eventNotifyDao")
public class EventNotificationDaoImpl extends AbstractJpaRepository implements EventNotificationDao {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void insertEventNotification(EventNotificationVO aPEventNotifyVo) {
       Session session = getSession();
       session.save(aPEventNotifyVo);
}
}
```

JAR should contain only these classes. I will share this jar to clients and they can start using the service by setting the VO.

As the dependent jars are anyway used by the module which uses this jar.

Comment: I tried using http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/ to export as jar. Still need to test if it works.

Comment: You will need the dependencies downloaded locally in order to compile your code.

Comment: I already have them but they are getting included in the jar

Comment: So I don't understand your question. You're having issues assembling the jar file? Some example code would help resolve exactly what your problem is.